# Constructing a torus

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, surfaces

A figure 8 loop is defined as two circles touching at a point. I need to show that a torus can be made by attaching a disc to a figure 8 loop.

I think that there may be some clever way to glue the disk to the two circles of the figure 8, but in truth I have no idea.

Comment: Would this wikipedia picture help? https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/Torus_cycles.svg/220px-Torus_cycles.svg.png

Comment: MixedMath's answer here should help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82553/torus-construction

Comment: Okay yes I understand it now! Thank you both so much!